# Super key and the main menu in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, menu, shortcut-keys

Is there any way to make Lubuntu 18.04 pop up the main menu when I press the Super key?  Most distros do this out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

Launch the text editor and open **~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml**

Search on 'lxpanelctl' to find "Keybindings for running Menu from Lxpanel". Look where the 'Super_L' string should be, edit it to what you see below, and save the file.

```
  <!-- Keybindings for running Menu from Lxpanel -->
  <keybind key="Super_L">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>lxpanelctl menu</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
```

Logout, login, and you should have the Menu at your fingertip!

And after editing, you must restart openbox:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

Comment: Good one! I couldn't get it to work, didn't know about "Super_L".